# Error while plotting bar graph in python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, graph

I have this current code below. The way the code is supposed to work is ask for a user name and then print all the projects and hours associated to that user within the called csv and then plot a vertical bar graph with the x-values being the project names and the y values being the hours for that project. I'm running into an error which is also shown below. How do I pull the right values from my code and plot them accordingly? I'm very novice with python so any help you can lend would be great.
Thanks in advance

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('Report1.csv') as csvfile:
  hour_summation = {}
  read_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  name_found = False
  while not name_found:
    # take user input for name
    full_name = input('Enter your full name: ').lower()
    # start search at top of file. Have to do this or each loop will
    # start at the end of the file after the first check.
    csvfile.seek(0)
    for row in read_csv:
      # check to see if row matches name
      if(' '.join((row[0], row[1]))).lower() == full_name.strip().lower():
        name_found = True
        hour_summation[row[2]] = hour_summation.get(row[2], 0) + int(float(row[3]))

    # name wasn't found, so repeat process
    if not name_found:
      # name wasn't found, go back to start of while loop
      print('Name is not in system')
    else:
      # break out of while loop. Technically not required since while
      # will exit here anyway, but clarity is nice
      break

print('This is {} full hours report:'.format(full_name))
for k, v in hour_summation.items():
    print(k + ': ' + str(v) + ' hours')

for k, v in hour_summation.items():
    x = np.array(k)
    y = np.array(v)
    y_pos = np.arange(len(y))
    plt.bar(y_pos, y, align='center', alpha=0.5)
    plt.xticks(y_pos, x)
    plt.ylabel('hours')
    plt.title('Projects for: ', full_name)
    plt.show()
```

Here is the error I'm getting. It is doing everything as it should until it reaches the graph section.

```
Enter your full name: david ayers
This is david ayers full hours report:
AD-0001  Administrative Time: 4 hours
AD-0002  Training: 24 hours
AD-0003  Personal Time: 8 hours
AD-0004  Sick Time: 0 hours
OPS-0001  General Operational Support: 61 hours
SUP-2507  NAFTA MFTS OS Support: 10 hours
ENG-2001_O Parts Maturity-Overhead: 1 hours
ENG-2006_O CHEC 2 Tool-Overhead: 19 hours
FIN-2005  BLU Lake BOM Analytics: 52 hours




---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-c9c8a4aa3176> in <module>()
     36     x = np.array(k)
     37     y = np.array(v)
---> 38     y_pos = np.arange(len(y))
     39     plt.bar(y_pos, y, align='center', alpha=0.5)
     40     plt.xticks(y_pos, x)

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

Comment: You want `y_pos = np.arange(len(y))`.

Comment: Sorry about that I fixed that problem but I still run into Len() of unsized object for y_pos

Comment: Update your question with the actual code and the error it produces.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Done.

Comment: Ok, it seems `v` is a single number? So you want one single bar per plot?

Comment: I want it to look like this 
https://pythonspot-9329.kxcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/figure_barchart.png 
with the name of every project below each bar.

Comment: This was not actually a question. It was a hint for you where your error is. At the moment you are trying to plot one single bar per plot, but that is not what you want.

Comment: Gotcha, I have it graphing now but it's creating a separate graph for each. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Yes, again, [edit] your question to show the actual problem.